# Using sshd_config to limit root login?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sshd

Using ubuntu 12.04, I want to use sshd_config to limit ssh-sessions coming from root to a fixed subset of IP's. I want normal users to be able to ssh from anywhere, but root should only be able to ssh from an IP-range (my local subnet), as well as from one IP outside this range (my offsite backup server).

Root-access via ssh is necessary for my backup solution, so using

> PermitRootLogin no

isn't a solution. At the same time, I don't want to unnecessarily endanger my systems by leaving root open for everyone and their mother.

I currently have the following in sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers *@*
DenyUsers root@*
AllowUsers root@local.subnet.range.*
AllowUsers root@offsite.backup.server.ip
```

where the local subnet and offsite backup numbers are correct.

This doesn't work. Any tips on how to get this working, and why? Documentation of sshd_config hasn't helped me understand how AllowUsers and DenyUsers interact.

Comment: Did you consider using [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) or [`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29)?

Comment: I can't get my backups to work that way. The only way I've managed to get working backups, is by allowing my backup solution a direct login as root.

Comment: There are backup solutions working over `ssh` which do not require `root` login. See for example: [Using rdiff-backup for remote backups](http://www.mad-hacking.net/documentation/linux/reliability/backup/using-rdiff-backup-remote.xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider simply using a SSH key to log in as root (`PermitRootLogin without-password`). Each key can be limited to specific source addresses using the `from="1.2.3.4,8.9.0.0/24,::1"` option in authorized_keys.

The manpage, right under "AllowUsers", *does* say:

> The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

– so if a DenyUsers entry matches, any other rules will not be checked at all.

Comment: And that `By default, login is allowed for all users.`.

Comment: `ssh_config` patterns can be negated using `!` but I have seen notes that this does not work with the allow/deny directives.

Comment: I wasn't sure how the processing actually took place, whether a DenyUsers could overwrite an already existing AllowUsers or otherwise. But if sshd simply stops checking after it finds any match, then it's obviously not going to work the way I want. I'll look into using without-password as logon for root.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config ensure that the following is set in the main portion of the config

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

And append this at the end of the config file. Now root can only login from local addresses.

```
Match Address 192.168.0.*,127.0.0.1
PermitRootLogin yes
```

I think this feature has been around for nearly 2 Major releases so... its surprising no one answered with this sooner.

You can do other things after the match also like enable port forwarding etc...

Comment: I've already solved it using grawity's answer. Two questions though: Does your method also work with external IPs (my off-site backup is on an external network), and is there any difference security-wise from setting `PermitRootLogin without-password` and explicitely restricting the authorized keys using the `from="1.2.3.4"` option?

Comment: You should be able to match against any IP local or remote... so you could match against the remote IPs you wish to enable PermitRootLogin without-password for... there probably isn't much difference but Match Address does solve over problems also.